# Build OpenSSL on OS X with build-type

Tags: macos, makefile, openssl, x86-64, macos-catalina

I am trying to build OpenSSL 1.1.1 on OS X for 64 bit architecture.
What are the options I need to give to ./configure so that I get the build for both debug & release build type?
Currently, I am running as:
`./configure shared --prefix=/path/to/my/dir darwin64-x86_64-cc`

Comment: Debug and Release would be different yet compatible and so they are mutually exclusive configurations.  If you want those symbols you can't optimize as heavily...

Comment: @RichardBarber Thanks for your reply. I meant to have both debug and release packages separately. The above configure command, make and make install gives me release openssl packages. similarly, I want to have debug openssl packages.

Comment: They would have to be separate builds and installed to separate dirs.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it will build in "release" mode. Depending on the configure script you use (`config` or `Configure`), it differs a bit:

To build in **release** mode for linux-x86-64:

```
./config
```

or

```
./Configure linux-x86_64
```

To build in **debug** mode:

```
./config -d
```

or

```
./Configure linux-x86_64 --debug
```